# Mobile breakpoint conflicts

Tags: css, breakpoints

There are a series of breakpoints I'm working with, but the last mobile breakpoint seems to be over-ridden by the previous breakpoint (max-width:980px). I've tried adjusting the 980px breakpoint by adding a min-width:482 in attempt to better target that queries, but it had no effect. This is the series of existing breakpoints I'm dealing with:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:760px), (min-device-width:768px) and (max-device-width:1024px) {
}
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) {
}
@media only screen and (max-width:1024px) {
}
@media only screen and (max-width:980px) {
}
@media only screen and (max-width:481px) {
}
```

I'm needing the max-width:481px breakpoint to be acknowledged by the browser so that the mobile styling will take effect. I know there is a conflict somewhere, but I can't quite identify it.

Comment: Looks like you're coding a desktop first approach which is not the standard. Flip your media queries around using min widths with the smallest min-width first to have a mobile first approach.

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful but doesn't appear to have solved the issue as it relates to the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume you know how CSSinterprets all declared styles

First Let's number all the media queries in order from which style will be applied first to last

```
// #5
@media only screen and (max-width:760px), (min-device-width:768px) and (max-device-width:1024px) {
}
// #4
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) {
}
// #3
@media only screen and (max-width:1024px) {
}
// #2
@media only screen and (max-width:980px) {
}
// #1
@media only screen and (max-width:481px) {
}
```

Now let's examine the ranges of effect, don't forget the order `#1` will be the first applied if the media matches if not then `#2` and so on

1. Styles withing the `#1` will be applied from `0px to 481px`
2. Styles withing the `#2` will be applied from `0px to 980px`
3. Styles withing the `#3` will be applied from `0px to 1024px`
4. Styles withing the `#4` will be applied from `768px to 991px`
5. Styles withing the `#5` will be applied from `0px to 760px and from 768px to 1024px`

If you can't see any conflict yet, then this should explain. don't forget the order.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some of these sizes doesn't work because are overwritten by the CSS order.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:760px), (min-device-width:768px) and (max-device-width:1024px) {}
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) {}
```

These two media breakpoints are overwritten by `@media only screen and (max-width:1024px)`

I see you want to use 5 breakpoints, but to avoid will them overwritten you can use 4:

1. `max-width: 481px`
2. `max-width: 767px`
3. `min-width: 768px and max-width: 991px`
4. `min-width: 992px and max-width: 1024px`

On conclusion, if the width sizes match only works the last order on CSS.